# Error in Hql - org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'null'

Tags: java, hql

I have write the following HQL,

```
@Query("select fd.fdNumber,fd.depositAmount,fd.period, fd.withdrawalDate, select max(fh.maturityDate) as lastMaturtedDate from FDHistory fh JOIN fh.FixedDeposit fd where fd.status in('WDR','RWD') and fd.withdrawalDate between :start and :end");
```

And I ended with,

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'null' near line 1, column 261 [select fd.fdNumber,fd.depositAmount,fd.period, fd.withdrawalDate, (selec
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
```

I search for a solution but I couldn't. Please help me with this.

Comment: @Query("select fd.fdNumber,fd.depositAmount,fd.period, fd.withdrawalDate,max(fh.maturityDate) as lastMaturtedDate from FDHistory fh JOIN fh.FixedDeposit fd where fd.status in('WDR','RWD') and fd.withdrawalDate between :start and :end");

Comment: You have two `select` statements in you query

Comment: oh... sorry I have put it wrong way. It is in this way @Query("select fd.fdNumber,fd.depositAmount,fd.period, fd.withdrawalDate, (select max(fh.maturityDate) as lastMaturtedDate from FDHistory fh) JOIN fh.FixedDeposit fd where fd.status in('WDR','RWD') and fd.withdrawalDate between :start and :end");. The secound select is withing para.